# Removing a internal PropertyMap from a Graph in graph-tool

Tags: python, graph-tool

For the purpose to save a graph without a specific PropertyMap (added with `g.vp.foo = vprop`) we need to remove it from a Graph `g`.

The PropertyMap is already present after the loading of the Graph from file.

How can I either remove a PropertyMap from the loaded Graph? (Or alternatively is there a way to copy only the Graph into a new one, without the PropertyMaps?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duhhh, found the answer just some lines below from where I copied the example above:

```
del g.vertex_properties["foo"]
```